# Looking for a compression spring alternative with 10x lifespan

Tags: magnets, fatigue, coil-spring

I'm working on a project where 100k spring cycles is gonna last a few months

Any recommendations on an alternative? I considered magnets but their sprigabilty isn't great (also, will they get demagnetize with constant repel forces?)

I'm working on a linear motion like that:
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/337136722090812189/

[image: SECRET MAGNETIC LOCK DRAWER]

The spring will be 2cm in length and 3-4mm in diameter.
Also, I can design it for a tension spring, will this make a difference?

Comment: Trees do well... think about how many times they get moved by the wind. So wood? Depends on space, load, design but you give so little detail.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/337136722090812189/

Comment: Can you provide a source for where you heard that a regular spring wouldn't be OK for this?

Comment: https://www.jamesspring.com/news/how-long-do-springs-last-answers-to-your-questions/#:~:text=The%20industry%20standard%20for%20these,with%20extra%20long%20life%20springs.

Maybe I understood incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Compressed air like an air suspension in a car or truck. 100K is not many cycles for a steel spring; springs such as engine valves run many ,many millions of cycles ,normally without failure.

Comment: Thanks! maybe I got the wrong info.

The compression  spring will be 2cm in length and 3-4mm in diameter, what material and type would you recommend?
Also, I can design it for a tension spring, will this make a difference?